# GMSAutocompleteViewController crashes after present

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

i'm using `GMSAutocompleteViewController` , the app was working fine suddenly  the app start to crash when click the btn to present `GMSAutocompleteViewController`   i was  using  **googlemaps** and google places 
i found that  2.4 was added `googleplacepicker`  with it  ,  i added it and still crash

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for 
empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x192b5efe0 0x1915c0538 0x192a3d200 0x101ceffe0 0x101cebdd0 
0x192af95f4 0x192af8d08 0x192af8a84 0x192b677a8 0x192a3c95c 
0x19354f970 0x198d96a9c 0x198e7ed90 0x198e81bd8 0x198ece9b4 
0x198e7ef60 0x198d140c0 0x198d14504 0x198d95478 0x1991aea00 
0x1006ddd54 0x198ca8838 0x198ca85a8 0x198d4809c 0x198d47870 
0x198d47424 0x198d47388 0x198c8dcc0 0x195e7e274 0x195e72de8 
0x195e72ca8 0x195dee34c 0x195e153ac 0x195e15e78 0x192b0c9a8 
0x192b0a630 0x192b0aa7c 0x192a3ada4 0x1944a5074 0x198cf5c9c 
0x1000b2714 0x191a4959c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
NSException
```

I removed the google places from the app and start  implementing it agin
 I removed my style, i also tried to use  `GMSPlacePickerViewController`  it  presented  but if I click search button it crash the same  .
all tis start after updating  pods to 2.4 , I tried to rollback to 2.3.1 but still crash
i'm not passing any array to the object

```
let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i opend a new Project  and  moved code to it 
here is callStack :

```
`2017-08-29 21:41:25.133 Client[16513:1632140] *** Terminating app due 
 to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM 
 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
 *** First throw call stack:
 (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b9d6b0b 
  __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b2a8141 
  objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b90bffb -
  [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 203
    3   IQKeyboardManager                   0x000000010804bfe3 -
  [IQKeyboardManager addToolbarIfRequired] + 3539
    4   IQKeyboardManager                   0x0000000108047642 -
    [IQKeyboardManager textFieldViewDidBeginEditing:] + 1234
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b975c2c _ . 
 _CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b975b29 
   _CFXRegistrationPost + 425
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b975892 
  ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b939102 -
   [_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b938261 
     _CFXNotificationPost + 673
    10  Foundation                          0x0000000107a91ca4 -
    [NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010a1cf913 -
    [UITextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 692
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000109afeb0d -
    [UISearchBarTextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 94
        13  UIKit                               0x000000010a1cf4f5 -
    [UITextField __resumeBecomeFirstResponder] + 52
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000109afee72 __45-
     [UISearchBarTextField _becomeFirstResponder]_block_invoke + 381
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000109afecf3 -
     [UISearchBarTextField _becomeFirstResponder] + 580
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001098e6171 -
      [UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 436
        17  UIKit                               0x000000010977f647 -
    [UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 137
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010a1ce8c6 -
    [UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 50
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000109afb9cc -
    [UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) becomeFirstResponder] + 48
    20  Client                              0x0000000104939085 -
    [GMSAutocompleteContentViewController viewWillAppear:] + 159
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000109878bad -
    [UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 447
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001098793c3 -
    [UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 147`
```

Comment: You are trying to pass an empty array. will you please post your code more so we can try to solve it.

Comment: i'm not passing any array to the `GMSAutocompleteViewController` here is the  all  code i use      `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
        present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil) }`  it's empty viewController  , after . a lot of debug and try . the crash happens  after  typing the first character  in the `UISearchBar` inside `GMSAutocompleteViewController` .

Comment: Have you enabled breakpoints? Which line is shown after crash?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem was the IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear.

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for 
empty array
```

You are using an empty array now. Try to find where you used the array and make it not nil. I think you didn't `alloc` it.

Comment: it didn't pass any array to it  , the only change i was  doing  on it was styling and styling is done by using UIApperance .

Comment: Try to find if other parts use array, might not relative with ```GMSAutocompleteViewController```, also clean the project re-build.

Comment: i created empty `ViewControlle`r  and test `GMSAutocompleteViewController`  it crash on present  ,  i created a  `UIsearchbar`  and added   results controller  it crash after typing the first letter in search bar ,  i created      `GMSPlacePickerViewController`  it contain  `GMSAutocompleteViewController`  just like the google sample  and i  it crash  when i press the  search UIBarButton

Answer (score 0):

You may not call GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey